# MongoDB aggregate $addFields with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

This is the second time asking my question here. If something goes wrong, I'm sorry.

I'm new to mongodb, I want to aggregate 2 collections using provider_id, tanant_id. with the following.

```
"provider_tenants": [
        {
          "provider_id": "63579dd4539180517fd51d71",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "_id": "6364da3dc6cded87a8d74086",
              "tenant_id": "636485fa84eedd81331c60e6"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "6364da3dc6cded87a8d74085"
        },
        {
          "provider_id": "6364871d84eedd81331c60eb",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "_id": "636b77aca99eaad39c86bd71",
              "tenant_id": "6364872d84eedd81331c60ec",
            }
          ],
          "_id": "636b7765a99eaad39c86bd6f"
        }
],

"details_provider": [
        {
          "_id": "63579dd4539180517fd51d71",
          "name": "details_aaaaaa",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "name": "xxxxx",
              "_id": "636485fa84eedd81331c60e6"
            },
            {
              "name": "zzzzz",
              "_id": "6364860684eedd81331c60e7"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "6364871d84eedd81331c60eb",
          "name": "details_bbbbbb",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "name": "yyyyy",
              "_id": "6364872d84eedd81331c60ec"
            }
          ]
        }
]
```

I want results like this The field entered when provider_id, tenant_id has a matching value with details_provider

```
"provider_tenants": [
        {
          "provider_id": "63579dd4539180517fd51d71",
          "name": "details_aaaaaa",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "name": "xxxxx",
              "tenant_id": "636485fa84eedd81331c60e6",
              "_id": "6364da3dc6cded87a8d74086"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "6364da3dc6cded87a8d74085"
        },
        {
          "provider_id": "6364871d84eedd81331c60eb",
          "name": "details_bbbbbb",
          "tenants": [
            {
              "name": "yyyyy",
              "tenant_id": "6364872d84eedd81331c60ec",
              "_id": "636b77aca99eaad39c86bd71"
            }
          ],
          "_id": "636b7765a99eaad39c86bd6f"
        }
```

Sorry for my english ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be this one:

```
db.provider_tenants.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "details_provider",
      localField: "provider_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "details"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      name: { $first: "$details.name" },
      details: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/80OHoeH4NnY)